# Unable to associate User and Profile Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, associations

I'm still relatively new to Ruby on Rails so I'm trying to figure this one out. I've done a lot of research so far but can't figure out how to tie it altogethe so that both my User & Profiles model associate with each other AND allow my Profile to save.
- I'm using the Devise gem, which registers a new user through the Registrations Controller.
- I have created a Profiles Controller.
- When a User registers, they are automatically brought to the Profile new.html.erb page to setup their profile. However, when I try to save it, nothing happens. However, if I remove the 'belongs_to :users' line of code under the ProfilesController, then I can save it without issue but it obviously doesn't associate it with the user.

- I have created the relationship between the 2 models where a User should have only 1 profile. I've also created a user_id in the Profiles table to act as a foreign key to link the 2 tables.

My User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

# Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

My Profile model:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  #after_create :create_profile
end
```

My Schema.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161126221219) do

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.string   "contact_number"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "makeup_type"
    t.string   "bio"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                   default: "", null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
end
```

My Profiles Controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @search = Profile.search(params[:q])
    @profiles = @search.result(distinct: true)
  end

  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new  
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
    if @profile.save
      format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Your Profile was successfully created' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entry }
    end
  end   
end

  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|

    if @profile.update(profile_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

  def destroy
    @profile.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profile_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def set_profile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:full_name, :contact_number, :location, :makeup_type, :bio, :user_id, :image)
    end    
end
```

I created a Users controller, which isn't created when setting up Devise but I wanted to override some of the actions. However, this is where I get stuck as I'm not sure what methods I'm supposed to override and how to do it as Devise is creating the user profile. Anyway, my User controller is below:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Lastly, I created a RegistrationsController to override the Devise Registrations controller so I could route the registration page to the Profiles new.html.erb page below.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
 # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

 protected
# This allows a newly registered user to be directed to the Profile Creation page
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_profile_path(resource)
end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    profile_path(resource)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `current_user` helper in the controller.

Instead of:

```
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:full_name, :contact_number, :location, :makeup_type, :bio, :user_id, :image)
end
```

You could use:

```
def profile_params
  params[:profile][:user_id] = current_user.id
  params.require(:profile).permit(:full_name, :contact_number, :location, :makeup_type, :bio, :user_id, :image)
end
```

Also you should add a `before_action`, which makes sure that a `current_user` is present, otherwise you should redirect to the login page.

Comment: thanks for your help on this. My profile actually saved without altering the model association and I could see from the database that the user_id was now appearing in the same profile record, whereas before it was creating under a blank profile.